# Retrieving json query from postgres and display in java

Tags: java, json, database, postgresql

```
String selectTableSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME from DBUSER";
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
while (rs.next()) {
String userid = rs.getString("USER_ID");
String username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
}
```

With the above code..I am able to establish connection with postgres and display values from the database table.
But how to parse a JSON Select query -

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
from (
  select USER_ID, USERNAME from DBUSER
) t
```

The resultant json structure for the above Select query in postgres is -

```
[{user_id:"123",username:"abc"},{user_id:"234",username:"pqr"}]
```

Not understanding how to read the above json "select" query from postgres and display the values "USER_ID" and "USERNAME" separately in java.

I am just a beginner.Any Help would be appreciated.Thankyou in advance.

Comment: [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) might help you to parse json to java object.
alternatively you can use libraries like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) for parsing the json to java.

Answer (score 3):

you should use [Jackson - ObjectMapper](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html) Class like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<User> userList = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, User.class));

for(User val : userList){
    System.out.println("User id : "+val.getUserId);
    System.out.println("User id : "+val.getUserName);
}
```

it also work fine

```
List<User> userList= Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(json, User[].class));
```

Answer (score 0):

let me suppose your model is like below

```
public class User {
 public int userId;
 public String userName; 
}
```

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert your JSON String (the return of your query) to a list of model (user in your case).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<User >>(){}.getType();
List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type); // where jsonString = "[{user_id:"123",username:"abc"},{user_id:"234",username:"pqr"}]" (the return of your query)
for (User user: userList ){
        System.out.println("user " + user);
}
```